# Start and stop the same interval multiple times

Tags: javascript, intervals

I'm trying out game character movement for the first time. I've successfully made a button that allows the character to move when the button is pressed and stops when the button is released. My problem is that this only works once. If I press the button a second time, the character won't move forward anymore. I checked the console for errors, but there weren't any. Here's my code:

```js
var sonic = document.getElementById('sonic');
var left = 0
var forward;
var add;
sonic.style.position = "absolute";

function move() {
  forward = setInterval(forward, 10);
  add = setInterval(add, 10);
}

function add() {
  left = left + 10;
}

function forward() {
  sonic.style.left = left;
}

function stop() {
  clearInterval(forward);
  clearInterval(add);
}
```

```html
<button onmousedown="move()" onmouseup="stop()">Move Forward</button>
<br>
<br>
<img width="150px" id="sonic" src="https://www.sccpre.cat/mypng/full/338-3383227_sonic-running-png-sonic-1-sonic-sprite.png" />
```

What I'm hoping is that the character will be able to move whenever the user holds down the button, rather than just once.

Comment: Do you receive any errors?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change delay in setTimeout using a button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58760890/change-delay-in-settimeout-using-a-button-click)

Answer (score 1):

- Instead of messing with multiple setIntervals use a single `window.requestAnimationFrame()`.
- On button (or even key) manipulate a `keys` Object, to keep track what key is pressed
- Inside a `keysController()` function convert the pressed key (if exists) into a `pos` (position) transform on `x` (and later even on the `y`) axis.
- Inside a `move()` function write the code that moves your element. Preferably using the GPU accelerated CSS `transform` property.
- Inside the `engine` loop simply invoke all your functions

```js
const EL = sel => document.querySelector(sel);

const sonic = EL('#sonic');
const left  = EL('#left');
const right = EL('#right');

const keys = {}; // you have buttons, but let's call it keys
const pos  = {x: 0, y: 0} // one day you could control the y axis too

function move() {
  sonic.style.transform = `translate(${pos.x}px, ${pos.y}px)`;
}

function keysController () { // convert pressed keys to position
  if (keys.right) pos.x += 10;
  if (keys.left)  pos.x -= 10;
}

(function engine () {
  keysController();
  move();
  requestAnimationFrame(engine)
}());

left.addEventListener('mousedown',  () => keys.left = true );
left.addEventListener('mouseup',    () => delete keys.left );
right.addEventListener('mousedown', () => keys.right = true );
right.addEventListener('mouseup',   () => delete keys.right );
```

```css
#sonic {
  width: 150px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<button id="left">&larr;</button>
<button id="right">&rarr;</button>
<br>
<br>
<img id="sonic" src="https://imgur.com/mYRJad0.png" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is a confusion of variable names. You have the same name for a interval index as you do for a function - so it's getting mixed up. See I have differentiated a little below and it now moves forward every time you click the button:

```
<button onmousedown="move()" onmouseup="stop()">Move Forward</button>
<br>
<br>
<img width="150px" id="sonic" src="https://www.sccpre.cat/mypng/full/338-3383227_sonic-running-png-sonic-1-sonic-sprite.png" />
<script>
var sonic = document.getElementById('sonic');
var left = 0
var forwardInt;
var addInt;
sonic.style.position = "absolute";
function move(){
   forwardInt = setInterval(forwardFn, 10);
   addInt = setInterval(addFn, 10);
}
function addFn(){ 
   left = left + 10; 
}
function forwardFn(){
   sonic.style.left = left;
}
function stop(){
   clearInterval(forwardInt);
   clearInterval(addInt);
}
</script>
```

However, I still don't think this accomplishes quite what you were wanting (continuous movement while holding down the button). Am I understanding correctly?

I've made some adjustments to do that goal as well below. I combined the two functions and brought in consideration of the edge of the window. I also added a lock/unlock mechanism for the starting and stopping. It's fun to make the little guy go! Brings me back.

```
<button onmousedown="move()" onmouseup="stop()">Move Forward</button>
<br>
<br>
<img width="150px" id="sonic" src="https://www.sccpre.cat/mypng/full/338-3383227_sonic-running-png-sonic-1-sonic-sprite.png" />
<script>
var sonic = document.getElementById('sonic');
var left = 0;
var forwardInt;
var addInt;
var lock = false;
sonic.style.position = "absolute";
sonic.style.left=0;
var rect = sonic.getBoundingClientRect();
function move(){
  lock = false;
  forwardInt = setInterval(forwardFn, 10);
}
function forwardFn(){
  if(!lock&&rect.right<window.innerWidth){
    sonic.style.left = rect.left+10;
    rect = sonic.getBoundingClientRect();
  }else{
    clearInterval(forwardInt);
  }
}
function stop(){
  lock = true;
}
</script>
```